# Realistic angular velocity for rolling sphere in Unity 5.1

Tags: unity, geometry

I'm trying to make a small 2D game with a rolling ball/sphere using Unity 5.1, but if find the angular velocity of the ball weird.

On this first image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Ksb.jpg), you can see the sphere in 2D and in its initial position. On this second image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLHHT.jpg), the sphere was moved by rolling until it made a 90° turn.

But the distance traveled by the sphere is greater than it should, if you wanted to be to be realistic :
you can see that the radius of the circle is equal to the size of the squares' sides, so the circle circumference should be equal to ~6.28 (in square side size). If the sphere was traveling realistically, it should travel ~1.57 (in square side size) to turn 90°.
But in the second image, we can see that it take 3 and not 1.57 .

The controller of the sphere is simply adding a force when a left or right button is pressed :

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rg2d;

    void Start()
    {
        rg2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, 0.0f);
        rg2d.AddForce(movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

So my question is : how can I make the angular velocity realistic in this situation? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for taking the time, I really appreciate !

Comment: You should try to tweak two things in different combinations: 1) angular drag of Rigidbody2D; 2) friction of PhysicsMaterial2D. Second one _may_ help.

Comment: Angular drag doesn't do anything, but the friction added by the PhysicsMaterial2D seems to work. Thanks !

Comment: I'm gonna make this comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the sphere has a zero friction and simply slides along the surface. To correct the problem, add [PhysicsMaterial2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html) to your sphere and set `friction` value greater than zero:

[image]